# How to delete unwanted quotation marks in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

I have this file:

```
shorts: cat, dog, fox 
longs: supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 
mosts:dog, fox 
count: 13 
avglen: 5.6923076923076925

cat 3 
dog 4 
fox 4 
frogger 1 
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 1
```

I want to convert this into a dictionary with the keys as shorts,longs,mosts,counts, and avglen and the values as whats after the colons. For the last part. that would be a dictionary within the dictionary.

I have this code:

```
def read_report(filename):
list1 = [] 
d = {} 
file_name = open(filename)
for line in file_name:
    list1.append(line[:-1])
d = dict(zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2]))
file_name.close()
return d
```

and the result is:

```
{'mosts: dog, fox': 'count: 13', 'shorts: cat, dog, fox': 'longs: supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', 'cat 3': 'dog 4', 'fox 4': 'frogger 1', 'avglen: 5.6923076923076925': ''}
```

How do I get rid of the unwanted colons and change the placement of the quotation marks so that it looks like a valid dictionary?

Comment: Try `str.split(':')` as something to start with.

Comment: (I've tried and failed in the past; could someone explain to the OP why `file_name` isn't a filename?)

Comment: if the last part is a dictionary within the dictionary, what is its key ?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file is named txtfile.txt:

```
lines = open("txtfile.txt").readlines()
results = {}
last_part = {}
for line in lines:
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue
    elif line.startswith(tuple("shorts: longs: mosts: count: avglen:".split())):
        n, _, v = line.partition(":")
        results[n.strip()] = v.strip()
    else:
        n, v = line.split(" ")
        last_part[n.strip()] = v.strip()
results['last_part'] = last_part
print results
```

will output:

```
{'count': '13', 'shorts': 'cat, dog, fox', 'longs': 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', 'mosts': 'dog, fox', 'avglen': '5.6923076923076925', 'last_part': {'frogger': '1', 'fox': '4', 'dog': '4', 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious': '1', 'cat': '3'}}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out JSON, it is a standard library onboard. Your file would look like this.

```
'{"shorts": ["cat", "dog", "fox"], "longs": "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious", "mosts": ["dog", "fox"], "count": 13, "avglen": "5.6923076923076925", "cat": 3, "dog": 4, "fox": 4, "frogger": 1, "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious": 1}'
```

And you python script will be like this.

```
import json
f = open('my_file.txt','r')
my_dictionary = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()

print my_dictionary
```

The output:

```
{u'count': 13, u'shorts': [u'cat', u'dog', u'fox'], u'longs': u'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', u'mosts': [u'dog', u'fox'], u'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious': 1, u'fox': 4, u'dog': 4, u'cat': 3, u'avglen': u'5.6923076923076925', u'frogger': 1}
```

[JSON!](http://json.org/) is so cool!